# Upgrade Dell laptop hard disk

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, upgrade

I have a Dell laptop and I'm looking to upgrade to a bigger hard disk. Please can you explain to me how to identify which types of disk are compatible? I'm totally lost in a sea of variants of ATA/SATA/IDE. I've tried the Dell website and couldn't convince it to try and sell me an overpriced replacement. Here are some specs:

- Laptop: Dell Inspiron 1300 B130
  (service tag C07RC2J)
- OS: Windows 7 Professional
- Current disk: Hitachi HTS541060G9AT00
  (http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?Item=N82E16822146042)
- Device manager shows these IDE
  ATE/ATAPI controllers:
- a) ATA Channel 0 (supporting my disk in
  Ultra DMA Mode 5)
- b) Intel 82801FB/FBM Ultra ATA Storage
  Controllers - 266F

I know about speeds, cache size etc. but I don't know what interface(s) to look at. I'd also love a 7200rpm if that's possible.

Please advise.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an IDE/ATA hard drive. They are the same thing. If you can find a vendor selling 7200RPM 2.5" IDE hard drives, you shouldn't have a problem with installing it.

You cannot put a SATA drive into that laptop according to the [spec sheet](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/my_systems_info/details?c=us&l=en&s=gen&~tab=2&~ck=anavml).

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Is IDE/ATA a specific interface or do you mean "IDE or ATA"? And there are different ATAs, so for example would ATA-100 be good? I'm keen to get a decent performance as I'm running SQL Server and Visual Studio on it but I don't want to drop the battery life to zero.

Comment: Well, technically your drive is ATA-100, but you can't find an ATA-66 drive anymore and they never made ATA-133 for laptops.